# How to call the method of a parent class from child class?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code. Whem I am trying to call the method of the parent class from child class I get an error called "declaration expected".

```
   Public Class ParentClass
       Public Function Foo() As Integer
           Return 1
       End Function
   End Class

   Public Class ChildClass
    Inherits ParentClass
       Foo()
   End Class
```

Comment: First, `Foo()` needs to be in a Sub or Function to be valid code

Comment: That makes sense. Why can't we directly call the method? I believe in Java it is possible?

Comment: since FOO is not in the child class in this case you'd invoke it as `MyBase.Foo`

Comment: I don't that you can put executable code outside a method, even in Java.